# AND and ORs with XPath. Querying only within the children of a node, checking all the nodes for children matching the query

Tags: xml, xpath

Lets say I have an xml structure like this:

```
<s>
  <a>
    <b id="myid">value1</b>
    <c id="test">val1</c>
    <c id="test2">valX</c>
  </a>
  <g>
    <d id="myid">value2</d>
    <e id="test">val2</e>
  </g>
  <i id="myid">value3</i>
  <j id="test">val3</j>
</s>
```

Notice the tag names are not important. Only the attribute "id" and the textvalue of the node.

The xpath query will be used to check if the values exists, so I can return the whole XML. This xpath query is done on a whole set of different XML strings returning those who match.

Now I want to use xpath to verify if either:

```
("myid"="value1" AND "test"="val1") OR ("myid"="value2" AND "test"="val2")
```

How would I write this as an XPath string? "val1" has to be on the same level in the XML as "value1". The same goes for "val2" with "value2", and "val3" and "value3"

I need to write this in a way that makes it easy to expand upon as this XPath query will be generated by code.

The input query for the generator will be on a AND/OR with "(" and ")". So I need to make a parser to create the XPath from this.

Examples:

```
q1: ("myid"="value1" AND "test"="val1") OR ("myid"="value2" AND "test"="val2") OR 
 ("myid"="value3" AND "test"="val3")
q2: ("myid"="value1" AND "test"="val1") AND ("myid"="value2" AND "test"="val2") 
q3: "myid"="value1" AND ("test"="val1" OR "test"="valX")
```

What I need is a way to make sure all the @id checks are performed on the same XML subset. So in this XML the check should either get a match from all the @id's directly below the S-node, or a match from all the @id's directly below the A-node, or a match from all @id's directly below the G-node. (and all other similar nodes)

If any match is done, I can return the XML. I do not know how many levels there are as the xml is very generic with the one rule that each value node has an @id attribute with the value name.

```
"myid"="value1" AND "test"="val1" should return a match.
"myid"="value2" AND "test"="val2" should return a match.
"myid"="value3" AND "test"="val3" should return a match.
"myid"="value3" AND "test"="val1" should NOT return a match.
"myid"="value2" AND "test"="val3" should NOT return a match.
```

etc.

This might be simple. But I have not found a way to get this done. Can anyone help me with this. Any hints are appreciated.

I hope I have made this understandable.

How would you write the same where upper or lower case is ignored. Like this?

```
//*[ *[@id [lower-case(.)="myid"] [lower-case(..)="value1"] ] and *[@id [lower-case(.)="test"] [lower-case(..)="val1"] ] ]
```

or is there a better way. The values are pre .ToLower()'ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for an expression like that :

```
//*[ *[@id ='myid'] = 'value1' and *[@id ='test'] = 'val1']
```

The result will be all the elements that have at least two children with an id attribute with the following constraints :

- one of the children must have an `id` attribute value that is equal to `myid`, the value of the element has to be `value1`.
- one of the children must have an `id` attribute value that is equal to `test`, the value of the element has to be `val1`.

Then you can add `and` or `or` as you wish. For example :

```
//*[ (*[@id ='myid'] = 'value1' and *[@id ='test'] = 'val1') or (*[@id ='myid'] = 'value2' and *[@id ='test'] = 'val2')]
```

Comment: Looks like thats a working pattern. Thanks :)  I did not know how to limit the test within the children of a node, but *[ test ] seems to do that.

Comment: If I wanted to do this check without caring about upper or lower cases, how would you rewrite this?

Comment: XPath 1.0 is not well designed for that, you have to translate characters. For example `translate(*[@id ='myid'],'ABCDEFG...','abcdefg...') = 'value1'`. With XPath 2.0, instead of translate, you can use the lower-case function.